# Spring integration with ftp skip files

Tags: java, spring, ftp, spring-integration

I am using spring integration to connect and download files from ftp.
I have two filters , one by file name and another one to accept only one file using redis.
To the most part it works great however i notice two issues:

1. Some files are skipped and not downloaded at all
2. Some files are starting to be written but stop before it finished and left with the .writing temporary file extension - I suspect it occur when i restart my service or when the connection to ftp server is lost.

Below is my configuration for an sftp connection but i also have two more vendors one using ftp and the other ftps who have same problem.

```
<bean id="eeSftpClientFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">
    <property name="host" value="ftp.host.com"/>
    <property name="port" value="22"/>
    <property name="user" value="myUserName"/>
    <property name="password" value="myPassword"/>
</bean>

<bean id="eeFilesFilter" class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.CompositeFileListFilter">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.filters.SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter">
                <constructor-arg ref="redisMetadataStore"/>
                <constructor-arg value=""/>
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.filters.SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter">
                <constructor-arg value="*.nm4"/>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="eeChannelAdapter"
                                 channel="eeFtpChannel"
                                 session-factory="eeSftpClientFactory"
                                 auto-startup="${ais.feeds.ee.enabled}"
                                 auto-create-local-directory="true"
                                 delete-remote-files="false"
                                 remote-directory="/SAISData/"
                                  filter="eeFilesFilter"
                                 local-directory="${ais.feeds.base.path}/eeVendor">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="500" max-messages-per-poll="-1"/>
</int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:channel id="eeFtpChannel">
    <int:queue capacity="500"/>
</int:channel>

<int:service-activator id="eeFeedHandlerActivator"
                       input-channel="eeFtpChannel"
                       ref="eeFeedHandler"
                       method="execute">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="500" max-messages-per-poll="-1"/>
</int:service-activator>
```

Your advice is greatly appriciated!

Answer (score 0):

Found the cause for issue #2 - 
The SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter check if the file was already processed and adds it to the metadata store - if the process was stopped in the middle due to restart the file isn't rollback from the metadata store so when checking again after restart file already exists in the metadata store and therefore isn't re-downloaded.